# Check which annotation is tapped, and use this information into a button code implementation

Tags: swift, mkannotation

I have some annotations in my map. I need to slide them with a button that focus on them, one by one. I use this function to see if an annotation is tapped:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView!)
{
    println("Annotation tapped \(view.annotation.title)")
}
```

How can i use it, in the implementation of my button function? This is my button code:

```
@IBAction func nextAnnotation(sender: UIButton)
{
    // here i want to know which annotation is pressed, so i can move to the next.
}
```

I have all the annotations stored into an array. How can i check what annotation is tapped, and use this information into the button code implementation?
Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear but to know which annotation is selected (showing a callout), check the map view's `selectedAnnotations` array property.  If any annotation is selected, the array will contain a reference to it (even though it's an array, it will only have either zero or one entries since you can't select more than one annotation at a time).